# Redirect to login page after registration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.1.0 and I am trying to redirect a customer to the login page after successful registration.

I make this "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in" set to no, after that, it redirects to the home page, but customer is also logged in.

How to stop the customer from being logged in after registration, and redirect them to the login page?

Comment: Your store need confirmation after customer registration?

Comment: how to create conformation for registration???

Comment: Stores->Customer->Customer Configuration -> Create new account option->Require Emails Confirmation set to yes

Comment: No i don't want any email conformation. i just want  after registration , the landing page will be login page for login

Comment: I override the createPost.php and comment the line "$this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);" , after that registration is successful, but customer is not login.

Comment: Now my issue is, how to set landing page on loging page instaed of home page?

Comment: Why don't you simply use this extension? https://magecomp.com/magento-2-custom-redirect.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply add following line into your overwrite class.

```
$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('customer/account/login'));
```

**OR**

You can do it using plugin as follows

**Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost">
        <plugin name="sr_Customer_Account_CreatePost" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Account\CreatePost" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Customer/Account/CreatePost.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Account;

class CreatePost
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    )
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost $subject,
        $resultRedirect
    ) {
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('customer/account/login'));
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this plugin works to redirect login page. thank you

Comment: @sohelRana, Thank you for providing solution. I have created the plugin as you explained, but still it redirecting to My Account Dashboard page after customer Registration. Can you please help me out from this problem.

Comment: @VenuJoginpally you need override the createPost.php and comment the line "$this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);" , after that registration is successful, but customer is not login.

Comment: Is it same applicable for login Post action also and other???

Comment: Try to use same way. It should work.

Comment: it worked like a charm! Thanks man!