# Magento2: How to disable auto login on registration from admin

Tags: magento2

How to disable auto-login on registration from magento2 admin?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean on frontend for customer ?

Comment: yes on frontend

Answer (score 1):

Login into magento admin area

Go to `System` => `Configuration` => `Customer Configuration` => `Login Options` and set "**No**" for `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` option.

[image]

Comment: This is already set No

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805752/auto-login-the-customer-after-registration-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are requesting is not present by default

for this you can create plugin and redirect to login page

here is the answer how you can achieve the same

[Redirect to login page after registration in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157362/redirect-to-login-page-after-registration-in-magento-2)